# How to raise and lower indices of the Poincarè group generators?

Tags: metric-tensor, group-theory, representation-theory, lie-algebra

I'd like to clarify how raising and lowering indices works when working with Poincarè group generators.

For example, suppose that we want to compute the first component of the Pauli-Lubanski operator:
$$W_{\mu}=\frac{1}{2}\epsilon_{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}M^{\nu\rho}P^{\sigma}$$
with the following conventions
$$M^{0i}=K^{i}\hspace{1cm}M^{ij}=\epsilon_{ijk}J^{k}=-\epsilon^{ijk}J^{k}$$
Thus for example if $\epsilon_{0123}=+1$ then
$$W_{0}=\frac{1}{2}\epsilon_{0ijk}M^{ij}P^{k}=\frac{1}{2}\epsilon_{ijk}\epsilon_{ijl}J^{l}P^{k}=\stackrel{\rightarrow}{P}\cdot\stackrel{\rightarrow}{J}$$
while for the spatial components, taking $i=1$ for simplicity
$$W_{1}=\frac{1}{2}\epsilon_{1\nu\rho\sigma}M^{\nu\rho}P^{\sigma}=\frac{1}{2}(2\epsilon_{1i0j}M^{i0}P^{j}+\epsilon_{1ij0}M^{ij}P^{0})=\epsilon_{01ij}K^{i}P^{j}-\frac{1}{2}\epsilon_{0ij1}\epsilon_{ijl}J^{l}P^{0}=-\epsilon_{01ji}K^{i}P^{j}-P^{0}J^{1}=
-(\stackrel{\rightarrow}{P}\times\stackrel{\rightarrow}K)_{1}+P_{0}(\stackrel{\rightarrow}{J})_{1}$$

First of all are those passages correct? Also I would like to know if for example I could write $P^{i}=-P_{i}$, because I've read that to raise and lower indeces of the Lie algebra generators one can only use the killing form, so I'm quite confused. I know that the killing form of $SO(3)$ is $g_{ij}=-δ_{ij}$ so it makes sense for $J^{i}$ to have a minus sign, but for example what about boosts generators $K^{i}$?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/751962/50583

Comment: Why doesn't multiplying with the metric tensor work?

Comment: Does it mean that index position is meaningless for group generators? This seems in contrast with the fact that $M^{i0}=-M_{i0}$... and I'm pretty sure that the latter identity is true.